# react dropzone: how to pass this as argument in place of props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a component class with an onDrop

```
class Space extends Component {
    constructor(){super()}
    onDrop(){this.setState({...})}
    render(
       const params = { onDrop:this.onDrop.bind(this)}
       return(
            <div>{MyDropzone(params)}</div>
       );
}
```

And in `MyDropzone`:

```
const MyDropzone = props =>(
      <div><Dropzone ... onDrop={props.onDrop.bind(this)} ...>
      ...
      </Dropzone>
      </div>
)
```

And this works.

However, as soon as I substitute `this` for `params`, it fails with an error: `this.setState(...)` is not a function:

```
class Space extends Component {
    constructor(){super()}
    onDrop(){this.setState({...})}
    render(
       const params = { onDrop:this.onDrop.bind(this)}
       return(
            <div>{MyDropzone(this)}</div>
       );
}
```

So it seems like there is a double `bind(this)` going on, and I am not sure why I need to perform two binds.  Why can I not pass `this` straight from the component?

Comment: `I am not sure why I need to perform two binds.`
You dont need two binds. Just do `onDrop={props.onDrop}` inside `MyDropzone`.

Comment: @PrakashSharma ah, gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in your second example, you are trying to pass `this` to `MyDropzone` as props. `this` refers to the component, but you should be passing an object of data. In your first example, you pass `params` as an object, so it works. Also, in your `MyDropzone` component, you don't need to bind `props.onDrop` because it should already be bound to your parent class component `Space`.